# Create a notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications

I want to create a notification with the class 'FirebaseMessagingService'.

How should I create a custom notification with a custom light colour?

My minimal SDK version is 15 and my target is 26.

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to implement firebase to your app to show notifications.
use push-notifications.

steps:

1. add firebase to your android project . you can see the step by step here.
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
2. the next step is to read and write data to firebase.
    https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write
    here when you read the data you can push notification. 
   if you want any further help ping me